# Is it worth including type_traits only to get the underlying type of an enum?

Tags: c++, enums, type-traits

I was wondering if it is really worth it to include the `type_traits` header just to get the underlying type of an enum. I'm creating a Flags class that I want to be as flexible as possible so I'm using `std::underlying_type<T>::type` to get the type. I could use `int` for example but what if user wants to use more than 32 flags? So my question is, could it slow down compilation times anyhow significantly when used frequently?

Comment: Measure the compilation with and without it a few times. Overall, it's really barely going to slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the std::underlying_type then you need it. No sense in writing your own or compromising your code. If you want to minimize the compile time, then forward declare the template class in the header, and utility the  type_traits.cxx in the .cxx files only, that way you don't necessarily inherit the headers you don't need in different files.

Comment: The problem with this is that i don't have any cpp files, only headers (it's a templated class) so it will be included in almost all files in the system.

Comment: You cannot use the forward declare trick for a type trait. The type `std::underlying_type<T>::type` must be seen at the place of use, it is not like a function for which a call can be done and expect the linker to figure out the address.